# How do you multiply between 2 listboxes and output to another listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox, multiplication

I need to multiply the discount and amount and output the result into the discounted price an the discount will be varying every time
[image]

```
` private void Discount_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button d = (Button)sender;
        txtPre.Text = d.Text;


        //Discount Spliitter
        var dis = txtPre.Text;
        char diseperate = '%';
        string[] displit = null;
        displit = dis.Split('%');

        string disarea = displit[0];
        lbDiscount.Items.Add("0." + disarea);

        //Discount Adder
        if (lbDiscount.Items.Count == lbAmount.Items.Count)
        {
            string strDiscount, strAmount;
            decimal discount, amount, price;
            decimal sum = 0;
            lbDiscPrice.Items.Clear()   ;
            for (int i = 0; i < lbDiscount.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                strDiscount = lbDiscount.Items[i].ToString();
                strAmount = lbAmount.Items[i].ToString();
                if (decimal.TryParse(strDiscount, out discount))
                {
                    if (decimal.TryParse(strAmount, out amount))
                    {
                        price = amount - (discount * amount);
                        lbDiscPrice.Items.Add(price);
                        sum += price;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid amount: " + strAmount);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid discount: " + strDiscount);
                }
            }
            lblSub.Text = sum.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Number of items does not match between Discount and Amount!");
        }
    }`
```

This is what I have right now but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: These are what the listboxes look like with data in them, i need to multiply the]

These are what the listboxes look like with data in them, i need to multiply the 3rd and 4th box together and output the result into the listbox on the far right. The discount is in a decimal form and will vary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it the old fashioned way, it'd look something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lbDiscount.Items.Count == lbAmount.Items.Count)
    {
        string strDiscount, strAmount;
        decimal discount, amount, price;
        decimal sum = 0;
        lbDiscPrice.Items.Clear();
        for(int i=0; i<lbDiscount.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            strDiscount = lbDiscount.Items[i].ToString();
            strAmount = lbAmount.Items[i].ToString();
            if (decimal.TryParse(strDiscount, out discount))
            {
                if (decimal.TryParse(strAmount, out amount))
                {
                    price = amount - (discount * amount);
                    lbDiscPrice.Items.Add(price);
                    sum += price;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid amount: " + strAmount);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid discount: " + strDiscount);
            }
        }
        lblSub.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Number of items does not match between Discount and Amount!");
    }
}
```

Comment: whenever i try to run the code and enter in the number it shows the last Message "Number of items does not match between Discount and Amount!"

Comment: Explain more about how these first two listboxes should interact.  I assumed they would have the same number of items in them.  Index 0  (1st listbox) multiplied by Index 0 (2nd listbox).  Index 1  (1st listbox) multiplied by Index 1 (2nd listbox).  Index 2  (1st listbox) multiplied by Index 2 (2nd listbox). Etc....

Comment: You could post a screenshot of your listboxes with some data in it?

Comment: i added a screenshot of the listboxes with some data in them

Comment: It should still work, though you'll probably want to change this line: `price = amount - (discount * amount);`.  Show me your code that uses the ListBox names.

Comment: what do you mean by showing the code that uses the names

Comment: I just wanted to see your updated code so I could help troubleshoot.

Comment: i've updated the code and it includes the whole sections, its under one button sender, and there is a splitter to seperate the percentage

Comment: I see your updated code, thanks.  How are items getting entered into `lbAmount` amount?

Comment: lbAmount doesn't actually work right now its all on a stub but ideally it is from the keypad and just the amount of items there are, this is a POS btw

Comment: "lbAmount doesn't actually work right now".  Okay...we'll, this line of code I put in, `if (lbDiscount.Items.Count == lbAmount.Items.Count)`, only let's it proceed if both ListBoxes have the same number of entries.  Otherwise, what will it multiply the first one against?  You can't multiply the first ListBox entry against nothing!

Comment: k so i have to get the amount working before before i can continue with this line of code,

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because:

- The specified multiplication is not implemented
- Your first loop is detached from the second. It does not even store its results anywhere, so basically does nothing.

There are different ways to fix this. My preference would be to avoid loops altogether and use LINQ instead as follows:

```
lblSub.Text =
   lbDiscount.Items.Zip(lbAmount.Items, (discount, amount) =>
      Convert.ToDecimal(discount) * Convert.ToDecimal(amount))
   .Sum()
   .ToString();
```

Comment: My fault, I should have checked the syntax first. I forgot that the lambda goes into the Zip function. I fixed it now.

Comment: now it just comes up with an error saying ''ListBox.ObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Zip' and no accessible extension method 'Zip' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: Have you added a 'using System.Linq;' directive to your file?